# excel VBA converting text to hyperlink changes sheet font format

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

i have a button that works somewhat perfectly. it does what i want it to do, to convert the entries in a column to hyperlinks. but after it processes, it messes up all the sheet formating like row height, font type, font size, etc.

```
Dim RITMRow As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim RITMstorage As String
Dim LastRow As Long




Set ws1 = Sheets("Tracker")


LastRow = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For RITMRow = 2 To LastRow


RITMstorage = ws1.Range("A" & RITMRow).Value



ws1.Range("A" & RITMRow).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws1.Range("A" & RITMRow), _
    Address:="https://snow.ubs.net/sc_req_item.do?sys_id=" & RITMstorage, _
    ScreenTip:="Request Number", _
    TextToDisplay:=RITMstorage


Next RITMRow

end sub
```

what can i do to stop it from messing up the sheet formatting? thanks.

Comment: With ws1

    .Cells.Font.Size = "8"
    .Cells.RowHeight = 11.25
    .Cells.Font.Name = "Calibri"
    
    End With

Comment: if you post as an aswer, perhaps it will help someone out down the road. Also it will mark this question as answered.